# loop count number of consecutive cell containing specific word

Tags: loops, email, google-apps-script, syntax, conditional-statements

I'm quite a beginner in JavaScript (well google app script) but now I can manage my work without it. My goal is to send an email to someone when the number of cell containing the word "alert" is equal to 3. I think that the structure of my program might be correct however the syntax may be wrong.

Let me show you what does my program look like for now (I want it to begin on row number 24 and on the 34th column of my sheet):

```
function onEdit(e) {
  let sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();

  //EVENT VARIABLES
  let range = e.range;
  let row = e.range.getRow();
  let col = e.range.getColumn();
  let cellValue = sheet.getActiveCell().getValue();
  let lastRow = sheet.getLastRow;

  let projectName = sheet.getRange(row,1).getValue();
  let user = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail();
  let cellLocation = sheet.getActiveCell().getA1Notation();
  let countAlerte = 0; 

  let url = "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/blablabla"
for (i=24;i<=lastRow;i++){
    if ((col == 34 && cellValue == "alerte")){
       countAlerte = 1;
      }
      else {
        countAlerte = 0;
      }
      if (countAlerte == 3){
      MailApp.sendEmail(
      'surname.name@xxx.com',
      user + projectName + '    alerte mol 1   ',
      url + '&range=' + cellLocation
    );
  };
  }
```

Is my syntax and variable definition correct?
Is there something wrong with my loop?

Answer (score 0):

You should add 1 instead of assignment:

```
      {       
        countAlerte = countAlerte + 1;   /// or just countAlerte += 1;
      }
      else {                             
        countAlerte = 0;                 
      }
```

That is regarding the counting.
Another thing is how do you want to catch onEdit(e). It would be better to get values in the column 34

```
var valuesInColumn = sheet.getRange(24, 34, lastRow, 1).getValues();
```

and loop through all values in the valuesInColumn array

for example:

```
if (col == 34){
      var valuesInColumn = sheet.getRange(24, 34, lastRow, 1).getValues(); 
      valuesInColumn.forEach(function(item){
        if (item == "alerte"){
          countAlerte = countAlerte + 1;
          if (countAlerte == 3){
            MailApp.sendEmail(
            'surname.name@xxx.com',
            user + projectName + '    alerte mol 1   ',
            url + '&range=' + cellLocation
            );
            countAlerte = 0;
          }
        }
        else{
          countAlerte = 0;
        }
      });
  }
```

Comment: Thank you for the time you took to help me! but is it going to count the number of "alerte" in my column and notify me when this number is greater or equal to 3? or is it applicable for the counting of consecutive cells containing "alerte". I hope my question is clear... Thank you in advance

Comment: I saw the word 'consecutive' in the title and edited the post, so edited version will count through array of values, reset counter to zero in case that some cell value is different than 'alerte' and respond with MailApp.sendEmail in case that there are 3 alerts consecutive counted. While you test the script, you can use SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert('3 consecutive alerts'); instead of MailApp.sendMail(), just to be sure that all logic works.

Comment: I tried to modify my script but whenever I run the program I get the message "ReferenceError: getRange is not defined" and I don't understand why ?

Comment: sheet.getRange() I edited it now.

Comment: Well, it works, but I have another error Message whihc is now "the number of rows in the range must be at least 1". So I guess there might be something wrong in the getRange() function as we specify the (last row)? I don't really know...

Comment: I suppose you clicked on the cell in the sheet where lastRow < 23. You can change var valuesInColumn = sheet.getRange(24, 34, lastRow - 23, 1).getValues(); to var valuesInColumn = sheet.getRange(24, 34, lastRow, 1).getValues(); Just delete - 23

Comment: Okay, thank you for your help. However, I just realised that from the moment there are 3 consecutive "alerte" messages in my column I get an email. But when I add other messages in rows bellow that same column, I will still have 3 consecutive "alerte" messages somewhere in my column, so I will get as much email as the number of row I will fill. How can I modify my programm so that when I put something different than "alerte" the count restarts at 0?

Comment: I edited. Next time, it would be more practical to submit a link to your sheet. I really dont have more time. Good luck.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the time you took to respond to me, and I'm taking your advice in account.